# Rational value of sine

Tags: trigonometry, rationality-testing

Given $x$, $\sin(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$, where $x$ is in degrees, we want to find all $x$ in the range $(0,90)$.

One trivial solution is $x=30$.

Comment: That problem asks for both sin as well as cos to be rational. My problem specifically tells that only x (in degrees) and sin(x) need to be rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ then $e^{ix}$ is a root of
unity, and so an algebraic integer. So $2\sin x=-ie^{ix}+ie^{-ix}$
is an algebraic integer. If $\sin x$ is rational too, $2\sin x$
is rational and an algebraic integer, so is an integer. As $|\sin x|\le1$
then $\sin x\in\{-1,-\frac12,0,\frac12,1\}$.

Alas then, the only solutions to your problem are the obvious ones...

Comment: Rather than x being a rational multiple of $\pi$, I want x to be a rational number itself when expressed in terms of degrees.

Comment: @kaushalagrawal It's the same thing.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks